# Pass lodash every() function as an argument to Rx.JS map() operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, rxjs, lodash

Why these two chunks of code aren't working similarly?

```
const a = new Rx.Subject;
const b = new Rx.Subject;
a.combineLatest( b ).map( merge => _.every( merge ) ).subscribe( r => console.log( "r:", r ) );
a.next( true );
b.next( true );
```

Outputs: `r: true`

```
const a = new Rx.Subject;
const b = new Rx.Subject;
a.combineLatest( b ).map( _.every ).subscribe( r => console.log( "r:", r ) );
a.next( true );
b.next( true );
```

Outputs: `r: false`

Aren't these two syntactically equivalent?

Comment: Looks identical to me, can you provide a debuggable example?

Comment: @jontro My bad, these snippers are NOT identical: map() operator invokes passed projector function with 2 arguments, what changes lodash' every() function behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting an answer that was written before the question was temporary deleted.

Lodash `every` accepts [2 arguments](https://lodash.com/docs/#every) (in practice there are [3 of them](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.4/lodash.js#L9143)).

Array `map` callback has [3 parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Considering that `map` is expected to call `every` only with first argument (value), `every` is called with arguments it didn't count on, this changes its behaviour.

It is conventional to provide existing functions as callbacks, but with caution. It's acceptable only when it's known for sure that a function accepts only 1 argument or the rest of them don't affect the result, e.g.:

```
const stringArray = array.map(String);
```

If there are doubts about that, wrapper function should be used instead, e.g.:

```
// will produce unexpected results because parseInt has 2 params
// const numberArray = array.map(parseInt); 
const numberArray = array.map(str => parseInt(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, these snippers are NOT identical: **map()** operator invokes passed projector function with **2** arguments, what changes lodash' **every()** function behavior.